# asp.net ajxa RadEditor problem

Tags: telerik

I put one radeditor on usercontrol  like below

```
    </Content>
    <ImageManager ViewPaths="~/Editor/Img/UserDir/Marketing,~/Editor/Img/UserDir/PublicRelations"
        UploadPaths="~/Editor/Img/UserDir/Marketing,~/Editor/Img/UserDir/PublicRelations"
        DeletePaths="~/Editor/Img/UserDir/Marketing,~/Editor/Img/UserDir/PublicRelations">
    </ImageManager>
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

but ContentFilters="ConvertCharactersToEntities" this property of radediotor gives me error

Cannot create an object of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.EditorFilters' from its string representation 'ConvertCharactersToEntities' for the 'ContentFilters' property.

how can i solve this error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using an older version of RadEditor which does not offer the ConvertCharactersToEntities filter. The recommended approach is to migrate to the latest one Q3 2011 SP1 to solve the problem.

Regards,
Rumen